With boost::MP11 how to apply template parameter one at a time?
I struggle to make something like following to work:
template< typename T1, typename T2>
struct Func{
  using type = boost::mp11::mp_same< T1, T2 >;
};

using FuncHas1 = Func< int >;
using FuncHas2 = FuncHas1< float >;

// Finally FuncHas2 = Func< int, float >, 
// which yields FuncHas2::type == mp_false 

Initially I assume this is a typical bind use case. However, mp_bind requires ::fn<> to be used. That requires extra code to be added into FuncHas2 definition, isn't it?
What I want is a way to let a type with multiple template parameters to take one parameter at a time. I want to do this because, I plan to apply the struct type to list1 (which has a bunch of parameters for T1) first and then apply it again to list2, which has a list of second parameters for T2. How to do this?

My update to elaborate the question
The problem I want to solve is this. I have two lists, one is ListOfTags, the other is ListOfTypes. Each element in the ListOfTypes carries a typeTag. ListOfTags includes a list of tags. The two lists size are normally different.
My goal is to extract elements from ListOfTypes per ListOfTags. For an example, ListOfTags = {tag1, tag2}. Then I want to extract all elements in ListOfTypes with tag1 to form a new list, and another for tag2 as well.
In order to do the comparison, I invent a function type as follows:
template< typename T1, typename T2 >
struct Func
{
  // compare T1 and T2 here and return result as a mp_true/false;
}

Func works well with my tag and elements in ListOfTypes individually. I, then, plan to apply Func to ListOfTags to form a new list ListOfPartialFunc, which include a list of partially applied Func objects. In my given example, ideally it would likes like ListOfPartialFunc = { Func< tag1, _1 >, Func< tag2, _1 > };. So all of its elements are incomplete types.
Next, I can apply ListOfPartialFunc to ListOfTypes to generate two different new lists with right tags.
The problem I encounter here is that since Func template requires two parameters so that it can not be partially applied. I wonder how to realize Curry mechanism here? I mean let the function take one parameter and return a new function until all parameter requirement are fulfilled? I investigated mp_bind. Since it require ::fn<> to be added at the second step ( to take the second parameter ), I don't think it fits in my scenario, does it?

It might be more efficient for you to ask your question with the list1/list2 scenario (to avoid an XY-problem). In the code you've given, you would write template<typename T2> using FuncHas1 = Func< int, T2 >; using FunctHas2 = FuncHas1< float >;, but I'm not sure that does what you want for type lists
